# how to pass the data from data.json file in react components with the help of props in react js?

Tags: reactjs, json, react-props, array-map

i am new react js , I have data.json file , i want to import the data.json in App.js and pass the data to respective components through or with the help of props ? i searched over the internet , but they are importing the data.json file in components not in App.js without use of props , so does anyone tell me with example or any exactly similar example link if you have please please share with me and effort is highly appreciated, Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can import json to App.js then pass it as prop to child component:

```
<ChildComponent json={json} />
```

then use it as you want:

```
const ChildComponent = ({json}) => {
//logic here
return (
//jsx here)
}
```

But its better to import json in components in which you are going to use it. It will prevent prop drilling.